# Как правильно сделать mock-сервис для тестирования?

Tags: javascript, angular2, юнит-тесты, mocking, jest

Пытаюсь мокировать имеющийся сервис на `Angular 5`, чтобы сделать изолированные тесты на `Jest`, но что-то не очень получается, хотя вроде все как во всевозможных инструкциях. Объясните, пожалуйста, что я не так делаю.

Вот файл теста:

```
import { PressComponent } from './press.component';
import { PressService } from './press.service';
// import { PressServiceMock } from './press.service.mock';

describe('HelloEweComponent', () => {
    let component: PressComponent;
    let service: PressService;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<PressComponent>;

    const PressServiceStub = {
        open: () => [],
    };

    beforeEach(async(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ PressComponent ],
        providers: [{
          provide: PressService,
          useValue: PressServiceStub,
        }],
      })
      .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
      service = TestBed.get(PressService);
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PressComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    test('should be created', () => {
      expect(component)
        .toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

При запуске получаю ошибку, будто `Jest` игнорит `mockStub` и пытается пройти по всем зависимостям из импортов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А ниже еще одна ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что нужно сделать, чтобы исправить подобное? Вот конфиг `Jest`:

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./setupJest.ts",
    "verbose": true,
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.jsx$": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.(ts)$": "./node_modules/jest-preset-angular/preprocessor.js",
      "\\.(pug)$": "pug-jest"
    },
    "moduleNameMapper": null,
    "moduleDirectories": [
      ".",
      "app/binomo.com/src",
      "app/binomo.com/src/app",
      "node_modules"
    ],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "config"
    ]
  },
```